# Dúvida no for e if

Tags: javascript

As árvores utópicas  crescem de uma forma particular, em dois ciclos:

cada primavera dobram seu tamanho
cada verão crescem um metro

Uma árvore plantada com um metro, no final do outono, qual seria sua altura depois de N ciclos?

Alguns exemplos:

- Se N = 0, sua altura será 1 metro (não cresceu nada)
- Se N = 1, sua altura será de 2 metros (dobrou a altura na primavera)
- Se N = 2, sua altura será de 3 metros (cresceu um metro mais no verão)
- Se N = 3, sua altura será de 6 metros (dobrou a altura na primavera seguinte)

E assim ...
Escreva a função `alturaArvoreUtopica`, que utilize uma quantidade de ciclos de crescimento, e retorne a altura resultante da árvore de Laura.

Já tentei isso e não deu certo :

```
function alturaArvoreUtopica(ciclos) {
  let tamanhoArvore = 1;
  for(let i = 0; i < ciclos; i++)
    if(i = 1){
      tamanhoArvore += 1;}
    else{
      tamanhoArvore *= 2;}

  return tamanhoArvore;
}

alturaArvoreUtopica(4)
```

Comment: O que já tentou? poste na pergunta...

Comment: quando o `i` é impar dobra a altura, quando é par cresce 1, você pode saber se o `i` é par ou não usando operador modulo `%` ex: `if (i % 2 === 0) // é par` ... começe com o `i` a 1

Comment: @vik , ficou assim
 function alturaArvoreUtopica(ciclos) {let tamanhoArvore = 1;  for(let i = 0; i < ciclos; i++)
    if(i % 2 ===0){  tamanhoArvore += 1;}   else{      tamanhoArvore *= 2;}
  return tamanhoArvore;}
mas continua dando erro , ele só aceita se o ciclo é 0 ou 1, os demais numeros quando é testado da errado. Tentei comecando o i =1 e tbm não deu certo.

Comment: tem de começa com o `i` a 1, e ser até `i <= ciclos`

Comment: @vik, agora deu certo, mudei para  i <=ciclos.

Comment: @vik crie uma resposta para ser aceita e finalizar a pergunta

Answer (score 1):

Essa sequência numerica `(1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 14, 15)` tem o padrão de 'dobro', 'mais 1', 'dobro', 'mais 1'...

Então teremos que usar uma variavel que vá alternado o seu estado mas que só tenha dois estados possiveis...

Pegar o valor do contador `i` e saber se é numero par ou não, serve para o problema.
O operador modulo `%` retorna o resto da divisão, então se usarmos `numero % 2` em numero inteiros, teremos sempre o resultado de `0` ou `1` (par ou impar).

```js
function alturaArvoreUtopica(ciclos) {

    let tamanhoArvore = 1;

    for (let i = 1; i <= ciclos; i++) {

        if (i % 2 === 0) tamanhoArvore += 1
        else tamanhoArvore *= 2;
    }

    return tamanhoArvore;
}

console.log(alturaArvoreUtopica(4));
```

Podemos alterar o `if else` pelo operador condicional ternário, já que ambas as condiçãos atribuem um valor à variavel.

```
tamanhoArvore += i % 2 ? tamanhoArvore : 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function alturaArvoreUtopica(n) {

var estacoes = []
var arvore = 1
if (n == 0) {
    return arvore;
} if (n == 1) {
    return arvore + 1;
}
for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {

    if (i % 2 == 1 && i > 0) {
        estacoes.push("inverno")
    } if (i % 2 == 0 && i !== 0) {
        estacoes.push("verao")
    }
}
for (var c = 0; c <= estacoes.length; c++) {

    if (estacoes[c] === "inverno") {
        arvore = arvore * 2;
    }
    if (estacoes[c] === "verao") {
        arvore = arvore + 1;
    }
}
return arvore
```

}