# Exercício For & If (dúvida sobre erro obtido)

Tags: javascript

Estava buscando uma resposta para um exercício que estou fazendo e, a plataforma onde estou estudando, devolveu com erro o que escrevi.

**O exercício era:**

As árvores utópicas  crescem de uma forma particular, em dois ciclos:

- Cada primavera dobram seu tamanho
- Cada verão crescem um metro

Se Laura planta uma árvore utópica com um metro, no final do outono, qual seria sua altura depois de N ciclos?

Alguns exemplos:

- si N = 0, sua altura será 1 metro (não cresceu nada)
- si N = 1, sua altura será de 2 metros (dobrou a altura na primavera)
- si N = 2, sua altura será de 3 metros (cresceu um metro mais no verão)
- si N = 3, sua altura será de 6 metros (dobrou a altura na primavera seguinte)

Escreva a função **alturaArvoreUtopica**, que utilize uma quantidade de ciclos de crescimento, e retorne a altura resultante da árvore de Laura.

A minha primeira solução foi:

```
    function alturaArvoreUtopica(ciclos){
    var tamanhoDaArvore = 1;

    for(var i = 1; i <= ciclos; i++){
        if (i % 2 ===0) tamanhoDaArvore += 1;
    } else {
        tamanhoDaArvore *=2;
    }
    return tamanhoDaArvore
}
console.log(alturaArvoreUtopica);
```

Contudo, ao enviar o exercício pela plataforma, ele não passou (eu deveria ter printado o erro). Entrei aqui para buscar alguma coisa sobre e [encontrei aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/424689/d%C3%BAvida-no-for-e-if). exatamente o mesmo exercício, com a solução abaixo (e que passou pela plataforma):

```
function alturaArvoreUtopica(ciclos){
    var tamanhoDaArvore = 1;

    for (var i = 1; i <= ciclos; i++) {
        if (i % 2 ===0) tamanhoDaArvore += 1;
        else tamanhoDaArvore *= 2;
    }
    return tamanhoDaArvore;
}

console.log(alturaArvoreUtopica(4));
```

**A dúvida:** eu não consigo entender por qual razão o que eu escrevi não passou e, a segunda solução encontrada aqui, passou. Se alguém puder me ajudar com esse entendimento, me ajudaria demais!

Comment: É porque tem um erro de sintaxe. O `else` está depois do `for` (note o fechamento de chaves antes da palavra `else`) e não do `if`

Comment: function alturaArvoreUtopica(ciclos){var tamanhoDaArvore = 1;for (var i = 1; i <= ciclos; i++) {if (i % 2 ===0){ tamanhoDaArvore += 1; }else{ tamanhoDaArvore *= 2;}}return tamanhoDaArvore;}console.log(alturaArvoreUtopica(4));;

Comment: O codigo acima roda dando 7 como reultado. Tá em uma linha só pq aqui só dá pra ser assim, mas funciona direitinho

Comment: Ótimo! Obrigada, @LeoCaracciolo!

Comment: E óbrigada @LINQ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Somente para ampliar os conhecimentos.

**Dentro do for use um atalho para a instrução if, [Operador Condicional Ternário](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operador_Condicional).**

```js
function alturaArvoreUtopica(ciclos){
 var tamanhoDaArvore = 1;
 for (var i = 1; i <= ciclos; i++) {
  (i % 2 ===0)? tamanhoDaArvore += 1: tamanhoDaArvore *= 2;
 }
 return tamanhoDaArvore;
}
console.log(alturaArvoreUtopica(4));
```

Além de eliminar as chaves `{ }` o `if else` também foi pro espaço. Dessa forma você não se atrapalharia com as chaves.

> > Importante também observar a resposta do JULIANO LANDIM a respeito do parâmetro a passar para a função

Answer (score 1):

Olá, você não esta passando o valor do parametro para chamar a função no `console.log`,
você esta chamando
 `console.log(alturaArvoreUtopica);`
 ao invés de `console.log(alturaArvoreUtopica(4));`

A além do mais tem erro na abertura e fechamento de chaves do if:

`for(var i = 1; i <= ciclos; i++){
       if (i % 2 ===0){ 
           tamanhoDaArvore += 1;
       }else{
        tamanhoDaArvore *=2;
       }
    }`

Comment: Juliano, então se eu tivesse feito o if dentro das chaves, o else rodaria normal e passaria o código... além de corrigir a chamada do console.log.